# Private member functors for a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, lambda, functor

I'm writing a class where I would like to have some member methods that have some data associated with them, specifically which mechanical systems of a robot they require use of. I thought I could write them as functors, something like this (this isn't my actual code):

```
class MyRobot : public Robot {
public:
  MyRobot();
  void runRobot();
private:
  Command do_something_,
          do_another_thing_;
}
```

And then initialize `do_something_` with a lambda in the constructor like:

```
do_something_( [] {
  do_first_thing();
  do_second_thing();
} );
```

And then tell `do_something_` what requirements it has:

```
do_something_.requires( system_a );
do_something_.requires( system_b );
```

And in `runRobot()` I would tell the robot's scheduler to execute the commands:

```
void MyRobot::runRobot() {
  scheduler.add(do_something_);
  scheduler.add(do_another_thing_);
}
```

But I have come to realize that as the number of commands grows, the less manageable the constructor for `MyRobot` will become, as every command will have its body defined there. I could make a corresponding private method for each command and initialize them with a function pointer instead of a lambda, but that just seems more convoluted. I could also subclass `Command` for each specific command and thereby have the body and requirements in a separate file for each one, but that feels like a lot of overhead for a fairly simple task. Is there a good way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why not have them as simple member functions, and bind the data they need at the point where you pass them to the scheduler (either through `std::bind` or just a simple lambda)?

Comment: Unrelated: please don't use the name "functors" for C++ function objects. I know it is used by many people; I'm asking everyone to avoid it. It is a misnomer. The word has a well-established meaning in CS and math and everyone will be better off if we don't appropriate it for something totally unrelated.

Comment: @n.m. I know what functors are in the context of category theory, but considering that "functor" is the most commonly used term in the context of c++, I'm going to keep using it.

Comment: @Xeo I could do that, but I'm going to have to pass each one into the scheduler multiple times and I'd like to not have to give it the same data multiple times. It's not very DRY.

Comment: @kunkelwe: Pack the binding into a function of its own. :P

Comment: @Xeo could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Command` class to take a `std::function` and an initializer list of "requirements" as you have them.  Then, instead of using lambdas you can make `do_something` and `do_another_thing` their own private member functions so you don't have to define their bodies in the constructor.  Finally, in the constructor you can construct the `Command` instances by binding the private member functions with the this pointer of the current MyRobot instance while also giving them a list of requirements.  The `Command` objects should be able to modify the private state of `MyRobot` instances.  An example is below.  Also, see [example output](http://ideone.com/tdq0aM).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum System { SYS_A, SYS_B, SYS_C };

class Command {
public:
  typedef std::function<void()> FuncType;

  Command(FuncType func, std::initializer_list<System> requirements)
  :func_(func), requirements_(requirements) { }

  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "Executing Command:" << std::endl;
    for ( System s : requirements_ )
      std::cout << "   REQUIRES " << static_cast<int>(s) << std::endl;
    func_();
  }

private:
  FuncType            func_;
  std::vector<System> requirements_;
};

class Scheduler {
public:
  void add(Command c) {
    c();
  }
};

class Robot {
public:
  Robot()
  :do_something_    (std::bind(&Robot::do_something, this),     {SYS_A, SYS_B}),
   do_another_thing_(std::bind(&Robot::do_another_thing, this), {SYS_A, SYS_C}) { }

  void runRobot() {
    s_.add(do_something_);
    s_.add(do_another_thing_);
  }

private:
  void do_first_thing()  { std::cout << "   FIRST THING!" << std::endl;  }
  void do_second_thing() { std::cout << "   SECOND THING!" << std::endl; }
  void do_third_thing()  { std::cout << "   THIRD THING!" << std::endl;  }

  void do_something()     { do_first_thing(); do_second_thing(); }
  void do_another_thing() { do_first_thing(); do_third_thing();  }

  Command   do_something_;
  Command   do_another_thing_;
  Scheduler s_;
};

int main(int, char**) {
  Robot().runRobot();
}
```